# How to perform a looped function on a list of data frames where the function requires 2 inputs from the data frame list?

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I am still fairly new towards the more advanced portions of R coding and would like help with making loops.

I have a multiple data frames that I need to perform a repetitive function on each.

```
Df1 <- data.frame(Col_1=c("A","B","C"), Col_2=c(1:3))
Df2 <- data.frame(Col_1=c("D","E","F"), Col_2=c(4:6))
Df3 <- data.frame(Col_1=c("G","H","I"), Col_2=c(7:9))
Df4 <- data.frame(Col_1=c("J","K","L"), Col_2=c(10:12))
DfList <- list(Df1,Df2,Df3,Df4)
```

So the data frame has the following format

```
>print(Df1)
  Col_1 Col_2
1     A     1
2     B     2
3     C     3
```

The function in question requires 2 inputs (2 different data frames contained within the list : Dflist

```
example_function <- function(Dataframe_x,Dataframe_y){
  X_Sum_col_2 <- sum(Dataframe_x$Col_2)
  Y_Sum_col_2 <- sum(Dataframe_y$Col_2)
  ratio <- X_Sum_col_2/Y_Sum_col_2
}

>print(example_function(Df1,Df2))
0.4
```

My aim is to loop through all possible comparisons of the DfList using the example_function to produce a data frame with the results, something akin to a similarity matrix. Like so:

```
      Df1   Df2   Df3   Df4
Df1   1     2.5   4     5.5
Df2   0.40  1     1.6   2.2
Df3   0.25  0.63  1     1.38
Df4   0.18  0.45  0.73  1
```

Whenever I attempt this it either tells me I haven't assigned the second variable (not sure how to do it):

```
>lapply(DfList,function(Dataframe_x,Dataframe_y){
  X_Sum_col_2 <- sum(Dataframe_x$Col_2)
  Y_Sum_col_2 <- sum(Dataframe_y$Col_2)
  ratio <- X_Sum_col_2/Y_Sum_col_2
    })
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument "Dataframe_y" is missing, with no default
```

Or it gives me this error when attempting a for loop:

```
>for(i in 1:4(DfList)){
  example_function(i,i)
}
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Any and all help regarding this problem is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Just do a nested `sapply` i.e. `sapply(DfList, function(x) sapply(DfList, function(y) example_function(x, y)))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `nested` loop

```
res <- sapply(DfList, function(x) sapply(DfList, function(y) example_function(x, y)))
nm1 <- paste0("Df", 1:4)
dimnames(res) <- list(nm1, nm1)
round(res, 2)
#     Df1  Df2  Df3  Df4
#Df1 1.00 2.50 4.00 5.50
#Df2 0.40 1.00 1.60 2.20
#Df3 0.25 0.62 1.00 1.38
#Df4 0.18 0.45 0.73 1.00
```